# How to correctly set symbol files for a windows phone crash dump?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windbg, dump

**Environment:**
Windows 8.1 Pro Update 1
VS2013 Ultimate 3 Update 3
Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 8.1

**Context:**
I want to fix the crash issue of my windows phone 8 app, so I downloaded the cab file from Dev Center, and extract the mdmp file from the cab.

I follow the instruction from this post : [Use WinDBG to see crash dump details](http://gauravsofts.blogspot.in/2014/04/use-windbg-to-see-crash-dump-details.html)
I face some problems when I do step 6.

[image]

**My Question:**
How to fix the symbol error for ntdll.dll?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503 Using the Microsoft Symbol Server with WinDbg

Comment: Does `.symfix;.reload` fix this?

Comment: @AlexFarber Already use that :)

Comment: @EdChum SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/2139026A0E93432682FCC93C36FF1F891/ntdll.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\2139026A0E93432682FCC93C36FF1F891\ntdll.pdb not found
DBGHELP: ntdll.pdb - file not found

Comment: That is very odd, it is not unheard of for specific versions of pdbs to not be available at the MS symbol server. It looks like you are running an ARM version, it's possible that this may be the issue, one option would be to manually install the symbols:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx and then set the symbol path via the gui or [`.sympath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff565407(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: From the screenshot if seems you have not used `.symfix;.reload` since the path only points to `C:\symcache`, nothing with Microsoft's HTTP symbol server.